# Working with date in sqlite on android

Tags: android, sqlite

When I run this query in sqlite tools I have a correct answer but when I run this query in my android project it returns 0.
Do you know what is problem?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Calendar strDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar dateAgo = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateAgo.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);

String query1 = "SELECT sum(Income.Money) AS 'Report' " +
            " FROM Income " +
            " WHERE Income.[Date] > '"+dateFormat.format(dateAgo.getTime())+
            "' AND Income.[Date] <= '"+dateFormat.format(strDate.getTime())+"'";
```

I checked all of my code but they don't have any mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MM/dd/yyyy` is not a valid **Time String** (see: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
Use this format: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: thank you, that was my problem. but I thought when date format in sqlite is MM/dd/yyyy in java code we should use this format too!! anyway thank you so much again :)